# Getting 'Invalid Syntax' When Trying to Increment a Variable in Python

Tags: python

I'm sure this is a stupid question, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why it keeps giving me an 'Invalid Syntax' error when trying to run this incredibly simple piece of code:

```
import os
default = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\'
i = 1
while i < 14:
{
os.makedirs('\\asnbackup1\\Backup Share\\Test ' + str(i+1))
i += 1
}
```

I've tried i++, i = i + 1, neither of those work either. I know I'm missing something incredibly stupid but I just can't see what.

Thanks in advance for your help guys

Comment: Yes, I know the indentation is wrong, it's only wrong on the site because I couldn't figure out how to do proper indentation using the code function

Comment: What are those `}` doing there?

Comment: @krongi: that's no excuse. With python, indentation is critical for understanding your code.  It takes just a couple minutes to learn how to use the system. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: To format code in stackoverflow, paste it, select it, and press `Ctrl`+`K`

Comment: The indentation was right in my code. It just contained the braces. It was already submitted before I realized my indentation problem. I see your point though

Comment: You can [edit] your post after it's submitted. Use the "edit" link at the base.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the braces, this is not C, Python uses indentation

```
while i < 14:
    os.makedirs('\\asnbackup1\\Backup Share\\Test ' + str(i+1))
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I knew it was something incredibly stupid

Answer (score 0):

In Python, curly braces (`{}`) are not used to indicate indentation; instead, indent. Your while loop should like this:

```
while i < 14:
    os.makedirs('\\asnbackup1\\Backup Share\\Test ' + str(i+1))
    i += 1
```

While you're at it, why not use a for loop with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#func-range)?

```
import os
for in in range(1, 15):
    os.makedirs('\\asnbackup1\\Backup Share\\Test ' + str(i+1))
```

Comment: Lol, I knew it was something stupid. I'm so used to languages using '{}' for loops. Thanks so much. I actually had just gotten it working using the for loop with range. Unfortunately it's not creating the directories on the share that I want. Thank you so much!